# PLS-00653 Error on an empty line (Aggregate/table functions are not allowed in PL/SQL scope)

Tags: plsql, aggregate-functions, plsqldeveloper, pipelined-function

I'm trying to run a PL/SQL Script I made but I'm getting an error: 
`PLS-00653: aggregate/table functions are not allowed in PL/SQL scope`

The problem here is not the error in itself but the line where it's being thrown from.

Here's my PL/SQL block which throws this error:

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE l_code_arr_typ IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(100);
    l_code_arr l_code_arr_typ;
    l_objet    objet_interface_pkg.objet_interface_typ;
    l_resultat CLOB;
    l_valeur   valeur_pkg.valeur_typ;
    l_liens    lien_objet_interface_pkg.lien_objet_interface_tab;
    l_rows NUMBER;
BEGIN
    l_code_arr := l_code_arr_typ('champ.fonctions.dossier.particulier',
                                 'champ.fonctions.region.admin',
                                 'champ.fonctions.ministere.organisme');
    l_resultat := '{';

    FOR l_idx IN 1 .. l_code_arr.count LOOP
        l_objet    := objet_interface_pkg.obtenir_fnc(p_code      => l_code_arr(l_idx),
                                                      p_acron_sys => :acronyme);
        l_resultat := l_resultat || '"' || l_objet.code || '":[';

        l_liens := lien_objet_interface_pkg.obtenir_par_objet_fnc(p_id_objet => l_objet.id_obj);
        FOR l_lien IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_liens)) LOOP
            l_valeur   := valeur_pkg.obtenir_fnc(p_id => l_lien.id_valeur);
            l_resultat := l_resultat || '"' || l_valeur.valeur || '"';

            FOR l_enfant IN (SELECT *
                               FROM TABLE(valeur_pkg.obtenir_enfants_fnc(p_id_parent => l_lien.id_valeur,
                                                                         p_code      => l_valeur.valeur))) LOOP
                l_resultat := l_resultat || ',"' || l_enfant.valeur || '"';
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;

        l_resultat := l_resultat || '],';
    END LOOP;
    <<<<<<<<<< ERROR THROWN HERE (EMPTY LINE)
    l_resultat := substr(l_resultat, 1, length(l_resultat) - 1) || '}';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_resultat);
END;
```

The error throws on 34:17 (line:column) which is the fourth line from the end of the code block. As you can see the *real* problem is that this line is an empty line. Moreover, none of the lines near that empty line contains a call to an aggregate function. 
 So where's the *aggregate/table* function's call located?

I'm wondering if the problem really comes from my code or if my [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwhLHaBRAGEiwAHCgG3p2v6uxqM5a0QRdptBOsx6LvviQciD3pz-sZuUGadvumV45oF_Sl0xoCHWsQAvD_BwE) is broken.

I hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!

The problem is that the function `lien_objet_interface_pkg.obtenir_par_objet` is `PIPELINED` and a pipelined return cannot be stored in a variable.

So these 2 lines...

```sql
    l_liens := lien_objet_interface_pkg.obtenir_par_objet_fnc(p_id_objet => l_objet.id_obj);
    FOR l_lien IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_liens)) LOOP
```

...need to be merge into one single line like so:

```sql
    FOR l_lien IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(lien_objet_interface_pkg.obtenir_par_objet_fnc(p_id_objet => l_objet.id_obj))) LOOP
```

However, I still don't know why PL\SQL Developer said my error comes from line 34 and It'll probably remain a mystery. If anyone have answer to this mystery, please feel free to let me know.